# Storyboard Two Scenes. Taking text from UITableViewCell in Scene 2 to UILabel in Scene 1

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, scene

I have two scenes in the storyboard.  Since I'm not allowed to upload images (new user), let's call them Scene 1 and Scene 2.

Scene 1: UITableViewCell with a UILabel, when this cell is selected, it takes you to Scene 2.
Scene 2: Provides users options  to select in UITableView.  Once an option is selected, it puts a check mark next to the selected UITableViewCell.

How do I get it when you click the Save button on Scene 2, it takes the text from the selected UITableViewCell in Scene 2, and takes the user back to Scene 1 and also populates the UILabel with the text from Scene 2?

I used storyboard to create the UITableViews.  Each cell has it's own class.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delegate design pattern to allow the two objects to communicate w/ each other ([Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)).

In general:

1. Create a property in scene 2 called delegate.
2. Create a protocol in scene 2 that defines the methods a scene 2 delegate would have to define.
3. Before the segue from scene 1 to 2, set scene 1 as scene 2's delegate.
4. When a cell is selected in scene 2, send a message to scene 2's delegate to inform the delegate of the selection.
5. Allow the delegate to handle the selection and dismiss scene 2 after a selection is made.

And as an example:

Scene 2 interface

```
@class LabelSelectionTableViewController

@protocol LabelSelectionTableViewControllerDelegate
  - (void)labelSelectionTableViewController:(LabelSelectionTableViewController *)labelSelectionTableViewController didSelectOption:(NSString *)option;
@end

@interface LabelSelectionTableViewController : UITableViewController
  @property (nonatomic, strong) id <LabelSelectionTableViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

Scene 2 implementation

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];   
  [self.delegate labelSelectionTableViewController:self didSelectOption:cell.textLabel.text];
}
```

Scene 1 implementation

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[LabelSelectionTableViewController class]] == YES)
  {
    ((LabelSelectionTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self;
  }
}

// a selection was made in scene 2
- (void)labelSelectionTableViewController:(LabelSelectionTableViewController *)labelSelectionTableViewController didSelectOption:(NSString *)option
{
  // update the model based on the option selected, if any    
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your swift reply.  So I followed your code.  Three errors:  
Scene 1 = STLetsMeet  
Scene 2 = STStartTransport

Error 1 is in STStartTransport.h:
<code> @ protocol STStartTransportDelegate <NSObject>
 - (void)stStartTransport:(STStartTransport *)stStartTransport didSelectOption:(NSString *)option; // I get an error on this line: !Expected a type
    @end

//Rest of the code in that file is fine as below:
    @ interface STStartTransport : UITableViewController
    @ property (nonatomic, strong) id <STStartTransportDelegate> delegate;
    @ end
</code>

Comment: No problem. That's a compiler error b/c the compiler doesn't know about the STStartTransport type yet (i.e., the interface declaration is after the protocol declaration). Add @class STStartTransport before the protocol declaration, as shown in the edited version above. Hope that helps.

Comment: Error: 2 & 3 are in the same prepareForSeque code.
STLetsMeet.m
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[STStartTransport]] == YES) // Error 2: Expected Identifier
    {
        ((STStartTransport *)segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self; // Error 3: Assigning to 'id<STStartTransportDelegate>' from incompatible type 'STLetsMeet *const_strong'
    }
}
Last, you mentioned the following step:
5.  Before the segue from scene 1 to 2, set scene 1 as scene 2's delegate.

Comment: I'm using storyboard and used Control Drag to call for Push from Scene 1 to Scene 2.  I did not use (and I'm not confident enough to know how) to use prepareForSeque to call the Scenes.  Not sure if that makes a difference?</br>

I'm a nood (i'm pretty sure that's obvious).  I have read 3 books on iOS and I'm still struggling.  Thank you so much for your assistance.</br>

Comment: BTW, adding @class fixed Error 1.  Thank you!

Comment: Error 2 is because you need to return the class object for STStartTransport. Specifically, it should be 'isKindOfClass:[STStartTransport class]'. For error 3, it's likely that you need to declare STLetsMeet as a STStartTransportDelegate. In STStartTransport's interface declaration (.h or .m file), add '<STStartTransportDelegate>' after the interface declaration (e.g., '@interface STLetsMeet() <STStartTransportDelegate>').

Comment: No worries. Even if you use storyboards, you will need to call prepareForSegue whenever you need to pass some information to the view controller that will be created. In this case, you need to tell the new view controller that you're its delegate so that it can let you know when a label was selected.

Comment: Erro 2 fixed.  Thank you.  Error 3, however, still remains.  Even after I added <STStartTransportDelegate> to the interface declaration.  
@interface STStartTransport : UITableViewController <STStartTransportDelegate>

I just noticed another warning in STStartTransport.m  Incomplete Implementation.  Method 'stStartTransportation:didSelectOption: in protocol not implemented.

Comment: Simulator now runs.  STLetsmeet (scene 1), when I click on the cell, it takes me to STStartTransport (scene 2).  However, now the program the crashes:  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[STLetsMeet stStartTransport:didSelectOption:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8864e10'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: Program cashes, when I select one the of the cells.  I need the text from the selected cell back to STLetsMeet UILabel.

Comment: For error 3 and the new one, it's saying that STLetsMeet has not implemented the required method in the protocol that you created. Make sure you define - (void)stStartTransport:(STStartTransport *)stStartTransport didSelectOption:(NSString *)option in STLetsMeet. This would be where you handle the label selection and dismiss STStartTransport. The text from the selected cell will be in the 'option' argument.

Comment: I have it defined as the following:
- (void)stStartTransport:(STStartTransport *)stStartTransport didSelectOption:(NSString *)option
{
    startTransportLabel.text = option;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
You were right, there was a misspelling.  The program stopped crashing.  Error 3 remains.  And after selection, Scene 2 does not go back to Scene 1.  Do I need to link the Save button to something?

Comment: So I noticed, if I click back after the selection, UI Label shows up with the correct text!  Thank you.  I CTR+clicked the save button from Scene two to Scene one.  But when I click the save Button, UILabel does not show the text.  It's like when I click on Save, I get a brand new Scene 1 and nothing is saved.  When I click Back, everything is saved.

Comment: Glad to hear there's progress. It sounds like you don't want STStartTransport to be dismissed until you click save, not just clicking the cell. In that case, you should send the stStartTransport:didSelectOption message in a method associated w/ the save clicked action, not in the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I'm in the SF Bay area and wife wants me off the computer (it's almost 12).  I'll try this in the AM and get back to you.  BTW, I learned a lot today, thanks to you!  Happy New year!

Comment: To get the text selected that way, just look at the selected cell from the table. Get the index path via tableView:indexPathForSelectedRow and then the cell via tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Hi.  Under the IBAction for the Save Button, I used the following code (and removed it from tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath).  
{
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.delegate stStartTransport:self didSelectOption:selectedCell.textLabel.text];}

Save button works, but it brings up a new Scene 1 (STLetsMeet) and the back button's heading is the original Scene 1's heading.  And no text shows up.

Comment: I need the save button to do what Cancel was doing earlier.  Instead of moving forward with a new Scene 1, I need it to return back to the original Scene 1 with the UILabel populated with the text of the selected cell.  And when I hit Cancel, I need to disregard any selections and go back to the original Scene 1 with a blank UILabel.

Comment: Sorry to hear you're having these issues, but I won't be able to debug your code. A review of these [tutorials](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/Introduction.html) may help. After brushing up on those topics, I'm sure you will be able to fix those bugs.

Comment: Ok.  I figuered it out.  So, I left UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        [self.delegate stStartTransport:self didSelectOption:selectedCell.textLabel.text]; Under - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath.  In scene one, I had to create a Exit Segue -(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];   
}  That work with the done button.

Comment: For the Back Button in Scene 2, I went in to - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender and changed the title of the UILabel back to it's original.  I think there might be a better way to discard any changes, but for the time this is working.  Took half a day, but I figured it out.  Thank you for your help again!

Comment: Also, to get rid of the warnings.  I had to add the following to the Scene 1.h.  @interface STLetsMeet : UITableViewController <Scene2CustomProtocol> and also import Scene2.h